# Is there a CSR register in RISC-V processor that shows the current PC value?

Tags: assembly, riscv

We are doing a project where arm64 processor is the main processor and an accelerator device has RISC-V inside. And the CSR registers of the RISC-V processor can be accessed from the ARM64 processor (address mapped). By the way some CSR registers are defined and added by our designers for our purpose.

Is there a CSR register in RISC-V processor that shows the current PC value? Or is reading PC only possible from inside the RISC-V core with an instruction like `auipc x1, 0` to set a RISC-V register?  I found some CSR registers are defined for exception PC or trap vector but couldn't find the current real PC value in the CSR register list.

I want to read the PC value of RISC-V core to see if the RISC-V instruction is being processed or not. But if the PC value is not reflected in one of those CSR registers, I can't read the PC value from the arm64 processor. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Is the RISC V processor stopped when you want to access current Program Counter?

Comment: We don't know exactly, the RISC-V should load the instruction first through IOMMU, and the IOMMU didn't give us a translation fault interrupt (before we fix the virtual io address, it gave us translation fault). We changed the assembly code of the risc-v to set a CSR register that we can access, but the CSR reigster didn't change so it seems the instructions didn't get loaded and processed. I'll look into it in 4~5 days later again.

Comment: So it is for debugging, not the final production system? And it is for one specific instruction, but it should be the accurate PC value, not off by one instruction?

Comment: We want to see if the program counter has increased. We have set the first instruction address and we are not sure if that first instruction has been run or not.

Comment: The list of CSRs on https://five-embeddev.com/riscv-isa-manual/latest/priv-csrs.html shows some that might be useful, like `instret`, the total number of retired instructions.  If that stops incrementing, the CPU's halted or stalled.  If it is increasing, it could be in a fault / reboot loop, though.  `scause` and `stval`, supervisor trap-cause and fault address, could be useful in debugging if those reflect faults in your RISC-V.  If you can write the CSRs, and your RISC-V supports debug / trace stuff, you might be able to have the AArch64 CPU single-step the RISC-V CPU with `tdata1` etc?

Comment: @PeterCordes Oh, instret is the right register I wanted to read (if that is implemented in our code). and this page is a very helpful information. Thank you!